# How to filter comparing two informations from the same Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a MedicalCertificate model like this:

```
class MedicalCertificate(models.Model):
    needs_leave = models.BooleanField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    days_off = models.IntegerField()
```

And I need to filter the active medical certificates, which are: date + days_off >= datetime.now()

I tried to use F(), but not success. Ex.:

```
from django.db.models import F

certificates = {
    'needs_leave': True,
    'days_off__gte': datetime.datetime.now() - F('date')
}

queryset = MedicalCertificate.objects.filter(**certificates)
```

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Why are you not using `DateTimeFiled` also in days_off? and It is `DateTimeField` not `DatetimeField`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to store the end date (date + days off) as an extra field? It should then make your filter pretty straightforward.

Comment: Dear OP, haven't you replied yet?

Comment: *date + days_off >= datetime.now()* - So you want to add days from your `days_off` to `date` and then compare with current date that your left value should be `>=` right

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter those medical certificates, which are greater than current date, so you can also query through days:

Basic Condition:

```
days_off >= date.today().day - date__day
```

You can query like this:

```py
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import F,Q

MedicalCertificate.objects.filter(
        Q(needs_leave=True) & Q(days_off__gte=date.today().day - F('date__day')))
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but did not work :((. Basically the same error as the initial attempt of the question. Also think it wouldn't work in cases where the certificate contains a date that crosses from one month to the next

Comment: @LeonardoGraciano Well, It will not give any error to you, I have tested it and it is working. What error you got? And It will also work in those cases where certificate contains a date, as I am filtering through days, the thing you need to understand that you can only filter through one thing, I considered to filter through `day`.  Have you tested it?

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer - timestamp with time zone
LINE 1: ...medicalcertificate"."days_off" >= (30 - "appDocs...
                                                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @LeonardoGraciano The model you shared in question is your entire model?

Comment: No... It's just a demonstration of it with the relevant fields for comparison

Comment: Can you put your original model and queryset how you are currently filtering? And also the error is from your side, the query is right according to that model which you shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246097/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-leonardo-graciano).

Comment: Hello @SunderamDubey Is this expression `F('date__date__day')` correct ? I think it should be `F('date__day')`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari It is correct, totally sure because `date` is a `DateTimeField`, so first extract date from it, then extract day from it. Can we also directly extract day from it?

Comment: Okk I get it but you've direct access to day so I think instead of making lookups large it's good to use `'date__day'`